# Insert data use tinymce in laravel. but display showing css style. how to remove css style in display

Tags: php, laravel-5, tinymce

Form Code

```
{!!Form::open(['url'=>'/about/save','method'=>'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">add about</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="text"></textarea>
        
        {{$errors->has('text')?$errors->first('text'):''}}
        
      </div>
        
      <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    
      </div>
     
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

display form image: [image]

font page display with CSS code: [image]

Comment: u can't delete the CSS from the editor .
it relies entirely on CSS to edit text.

Comment: Yeah, that is the expected output otherwise, how else would it change the output?

Comment: So how can I use text editor my input type, Where do not dispaly show up css code?

Comment: First learn how to ask clean questions on stackoverfollow. Down voted @TiShohagh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your data in view with `{!! $text !!}` not with `{{ $text }}`.